# Powerpivot duplicating values

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot, powerpivot

I have two tables:

- First table contains sales pipeline information for accounts (contains pipeline ID, accountID, and pipeline value). Each account IDs have multiple pipeline ID
- Second table includes the number of employees per account.

I included these tables to powerpivot, and I created relationship based on account ID.

I would like to create pivot that tells by Number of employees & Pipeline value by account ID and PipeID.
However, when implemented, it repeates all pipeID for each account. Even those pipeIDs which are not related to the account.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1Ga.png

Could someone point me to a right direction to how I tweak the pivot to show only relevant pipeID?

I would appreciate any help you could provide...

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers repeat in your pivot table because Number of Employees is not related to Pipeline ID.  This is Excel's default reaction to missing relationships. To get rid of the repeating numbers and keep this pivot table as is you need to find a way to relate number of employees to a pipeline ID.

If I were modeling this, I would have a separate table that is just distinct Account IDs, to make it it's own dimension. Then have your two tables you mentioned in the question.

If you were simply writing a query against this data, how you would connect pipeline ID to number of employees?  To which pipeline should an employee be attached ? If there is a way to do this manually/in a query, adjust your two tables to both include the fields on which you would join. I don't think you would be able to relate Number of Employees to Pipeline ID, so I would remove Pipeline ID from the pivot table. Then the numbers should be correct. You would want to create another pivot to show pipeline by pipeline ID per account.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I were to do this in SQL, I would just append/insert the either information to either table. it would show me all the information at the CRM ID level, but I could leave the pipeID if a user wants to expend on pipeID to understand pipeline information. I'm not sure if I can get to the same solution with powerpivot...

Comment: But how do you know which pipeline ID an employee should be tied to?  Basically, can you tell me what the values in the pivot table should be?